# A matrix optimization problem that resembles a standard semidefinite program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

I have a constrained matrix optimization problem as follows

\begin{align} 
\max\limits_{X} \;\; &\mbox{tr}\Big( \left(C - \frac{1}{2} B R^{-1} S \right) \Lambda X^T \Big) \\ 
\text{subject to} \;\; &\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
-\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}S\Lambda X^T & X \Lambda^{1/2}  \\
\Lambda^{1/2} X^T & I
\end{array}
\right] \succeq 0 \\
&R^{-1}S\Lambda X^T = (R^{-1}S\Lambda X^T)^T
\end{align}

where $R$ is symmetric and $\Lambda$ is symmetric and positive-semi-definite.

I am trying to prove that this is a semidefinite program. The objective is linear in the entries of the matrix variable $X$ and I have a PSD constraint. However, I read [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/semidef_prog.pdf) that a standard SDP involves minimization of a linear objective function subject to an **affine combination of symmetric matrices** being positive-semidefinite. I can prove that when $X$ is scalar, this program is indeed an SDP according to this criterion. However, for the general matrix case, I cannot show that the PSD constraint involves an **affine combination of symmetric matrices**. Moreover, I do not know if the equality constraint can be handled in a standard SDP. I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading about one standard form, and about one side of the primal-dual pairs. These are not set in stone, although they all are about linearly parameterized matrices constrained to be semidefinite.

One way to define a standard semidefinite program (from the dual, LMI form) is $\max_y b^Ty$ subject to $\mathcal{C}-\mathcal{A}(y)\succeq 0, Fy = f$ where $\mathcal{C}-\mathcal{A}(y)$ represent a set of linear matrix inequalities in $y$. Solvers define problems through the data $\{b,\mathcal{C},\mathcal{A},F,f\}$.

In your case, introduce a symmetric matrix $Z$ to replace $\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}S\Lambda X^T$, add the associated equality, and you have a semidefinite program in required form, with $y$ being the unique elements in $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: Hi @Johan I tried solving the SDP posed above using yalmip. However, even for the simple scalar case I get the error  info:     'No suitable solver' ,   followed by     problem: -2  , any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: You should post YALMIP-specific question to the YALMIP Google groups. The diagnostics indicates that you don't have any SDP solver installed.

Comment: thanks, I just posted my inquiry in the dedicated forum. Isn't the YALMIP package self-contained? I see a folder called "solvers". Aren't the solvers made accessible in the package itself or should separately download a solver?

Comment: YALMIP is only a modelling language, with interfaces to various solvers.